# How to find the owner of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do i find the owner / admin of an Facebook page, where the owner isn't listed in the info?
Is there a trick I can do with the Facebook API or javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Nope - this information is not available via the API, nor via facebook.com itself.

It is a privacy issue - the administrator/owner of the page might not wish to disclaim personal information about themselves just because it's their job to maintain someones Facebook page. Facebook portrays pages of companies/products/artists/etc as entities within themselves and don't publicly associate them with any other accounts.

---

The closest I think you'll be able to get is for a band page where the members, manager and booking agent's information might be available. This is not however guaranteed to have any indication of the Facebook account(s) that is managing the page.

`http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/
shpongle/?fields=about,bio,band_members,press_contact`

```
{
  "about": "Shpongle are Simon Posford (aka Hallucinogen/Younger Brother) and Raja Ram (Quintessence, 1200 mics and The Infinity Project). Simon takes care of the production, instrumentation and programming, while Raja Ram is the flautist and Cunning Linguist.", 
  "bio": "Shpongle (pronounced /ˈʃpɒŋɡəl/) is a psychedelic downtempo or Psybient music project. The members are Simon Posford (aka Hallucinogen) and Raja Ram (one third of The Infinity Project). Simon takes care of the production, instrumentation and programming, while Raja Ram is the flautist and Cunning Linguist. They DJ separately and together, Simon having just completed 52 shows in the USA touring with a visual extravaganza known as 'The Shpongletron'. \nDongle and Mongle are the only two other words rhyming with Shpongle...a strange hybrid of electronic manipulation and shamanic midgets with frozen digits squeezing the envelope and crawling through the doors of perception, find a new pair of dice...extra numbers and colours an infinite expanding bubble, filled with a bizzare, strange world of dripping hallucinatory wallpaper, a garden of earthly delights...........Shpongleland.....a place of well being, and reflective surfaces, morphing like an anacondas skin and shimmering like a million colour changing squid, at fifty fathoms.. truly unfathomable like seperating water from it's wetness, the Ineffable Mysteries unweave .....", 
  "band_members": "SImon Posford & Raja Ram", 
  "press_contact": "Stephanie J. Morgan | smorgan@c3presents.com", 
  "id": "78005158945"
}
```

Comment: +1 - also, you can always send a message to the page with the facebook function